# nodejs -nodemailer cannot send email after allowing less secure apps access

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

This is my first time using nodejs with nodemailer to send an email from a dummy account I have .When trying to send an email I got the error

```
"  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w17sm3259346ejk.112 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'"
```

My credentials are correct and I have enabled access from less secure apps to my gmail account.I also tried removing @gmail.com from my user but I still get the same error .

My code :

```
const mailer = require('nodemailer');

const  transporter = mailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  port:587,
  auth: {
    user: 'test@gmail.com',
    pass: 'my pass '
  }
});

const  mailOptions = {
  from: 'test@gmail.com',
  to: 'bill@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};



function sendEmail(){

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
  
}

module.exports = {sendEmail};
```

I would appreciate your help here . Please don't mark this as a duplicate as I have already searched here .

Answer (score 0):

Receiver's mail also should enabled less secure apps. otherwise your mail not reach the destination.

Answer (score 0):

**New Approach**

Google has a new approach of sending email using third party API & packages like nodemailer, if you are still facing issues consider having a look on this issue, it may help a lot.

Check: [Full StackOverflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530276/how-to-send-emails-with-google-using-nodemailer-after-google-disabled-less-sure)

---

**This may still help some people**

*You also need to temporary allow access to your account in order to sign in on your new application or device.
Use: [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha*)