# How to send emails with google using nodemailer after Google disabled less sure app option?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, gmail, nodemailer

I would like to find a way to send email from my app using `nodemailer` to the users either with some kind of google authentication or any other way. Below mentioned working code has stopped working after Google has disabled less secure app option.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const sendEmail = async options => {
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    // host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    // port: "465",
    // secure: true,
    service:'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: "USER_EMAIL",
        pass: "USER_PASSWORD"
    },
    tls:{rejectUnauthorized:false}
})

const message = {
    from: `${process.env.FROM_NAME} <${process.env.FROM_EMAIL}>`,
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
    html: options.message,
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: '.png',
            path: __dirname + '.png',
            cid: '.png'
        }
    ]
}

const info = await transporter.sendMail(message)
console.log('Message sent : %s', info.messageId)
console.log(__dirname)
}
module.exports = sendEmail
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72481551/14673170

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At the time of writing, Less Secure Apps is no longer supported by google. And you can't use your google account password.

You're gonna have to generate a new app password.

App passwords only work if 2-step verification is turned on.
Follow this steps to get the app password

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Enable 2FA
3. Create App Password for Email
4. Copy that password (16 characters) into the pass parameter in Nodemailer auth.

```
const client = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "username@gmail.com",
        pass: "Google-App-Password-Without-Spaces"
    }
});

client.sendMail(
    {
        from: "sender",
        to: "recipient",
        subject: "Sending it from Heroku",
        text: "Hey, I'm being sent from the cloud"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).

Nodmailer supports serval types of [Oauth](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/)

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: "user@example.com",
    clientId: "000000000000-xxx0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "XxxxxXXxX0xxxxxxxx0XXxX0",
    refreshToken: "1/XXxXxsss-xxxXXXXXxXxx0XXXxxXXx0x00xxx",
    accessToken: "ya29.Xx_XX0xxxxx-xX0X0XxXXxXxXXXxX0x",
    expires: 1484314697598,
  },
});
```

Comment: do i need to set up my google cloud platform for that right?

Comment: You need a project on [Google developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) with gmail api enabled this is where you will get the client id and client secret for the code above