# Although password is correct but Nodemailer error - Error: Invalid login: 535 Incorrect authentication data

Tags: node.js, email, html-email, nodemailer, nodejs-server

Getting this error instead of using current email and password

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function sendEmail(sendTo, subject, text, html) {
  try {

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL_HOST,
      port: 465,
      secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL, // generated ethereal user
        pass: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD, // generated ethereal password
      },
    });

    let to = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < sendTo.length; i += 1) {
      to += `${sendTo[i]}, `;
    }

    // send mail with defined transport object
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"Fred Foo " <${process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL}>`, // sender address
      to, // list of receivers
      subject, // Subject line
      text, // plain text body
      html, // html body
    });

    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

Calling the function

```
await sendEmail(
        [email],
        'verify studio',
        'Please verify your studio',
        message
      );
```

Error

```
Error: Invalid login: 535 Incorrect authentication data
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:787:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1539:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:543:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:950:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:752:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/home/shayon/Documents/nodejs-nextjs-lms/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:191:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 Incorrect authentication data',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Comment: Did this code ever worked before ? And if not, did you make sure that you enabled the possibility to connect through such application ? I've juste seen that gmail disabled the possiblity to use less secure apps option to connect, so maybe this is your issue. Here is a link of another issue that is adressing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530276/nodemailergoogle-disabled-the-less-secure-app-option-on-google-accounts-i-woul